# No error for two traits implementing the same method

Tags: rust, mio

According to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ufcs.html), Rust should complain if I try to call a method provided by two different traits like this:

```
trait Foo {
    fn f(&self);
}

trait Bar {
    fn f(&self);
}

struct Baz;

impl Foo for Baz {
    fn f(&self) { println!("Baz’s impl of Foo"); }
}

impl Bar for Baz {
    fn f(&self) { println!("Baz’s impl of Bar"); }
}

fn main(){
    let b = Baz;
    b.f();
}
```

Running this results in the expected `error: multiple applicable methods in scope` error.

However I get no error for this:

```
extern crate mio;
use mio::buf::RingBuf;
use mio::buf::Buf;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let buf = RingBuf::new(10);
    let bytes = buf.bytes();
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

`mio::buf::RingBuf` implements both `Buf` and `Read`. Both traits provide a `bytes` method.

I would expect Rust to complain with the same error as above. Instead it silently chooses the "wrong" implementation and later `println` complains about the wrong type.

Any idea why I don't get an error here?

If I remove `use std::io::Read;` everything works fine. But with that trait in scope suddenly the implementation of Read is used and bytes has the "wrong" type.

(I am using Rust 1.0.0)

Comment: Please report this on [rust's issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues)

Comment: I already did: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26080 - not sure if it was the perfect place.

Comment: thank you, I think that's the place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@bluss found the problem:

```
struct Type;

trait A {
    fn foo(&self) -> bool { false }
}

trait B : Sized {
    fn foo(self) -> bool { true }
}

impl A for Type { }
impl B for Type { }

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Type.foo());   // This will call B::foo -- it will prefer `self`.
}
```

If both types use a slightly different `self` type, Rust treats them as different and calling the method simply prefers one of them.

This is probably a bug in Rust. For details have a look at the corresponding [Rust issue](http://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26080).

Comment: I was just stumped that it worked like this, and now I don't think we can call it a bug. Rust is stable so we need to get friendly with this feature. :-|